# Intra-package references + cython

Tags: python, import, cython

Good afternoon everybody.
I wishes you all the best for this new year 2016.

I'm cythonising my code, and I'm new to it.

My structure is:

```
.
MotorControlModel
    ├─ runTest.py
    ├─ ArmModel
        ├─ Arm.pyx
        ├─ Arm.pxd
        ├─ ArmParameters.pxd
        ├─ ArmParameters.pyx
        ├─ MusclesParameters.pxd
        ├─ MusclesParameters.pyd
```

**Arm.pxd:**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

import MusclesParameters 
from MusclesParameters cimport MusclesParameters

import ArmParameters
from ArmParameters cimport ArmParameters

cdef class Arm:
...
```

**ArmParameters.pxd :**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class ArmParameters :
...
```

**MusclesParameters.pxd :**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef class MusclesParameters:
...
```

**runTest.py :**

```
import numpy as np
import os    
import ArmModel

print("--------------Muscles---------------")

from ArmModel import MusclesParameters as MusclesParam    
Muscles = MusclesParam.MusclesParameters()

print("--------------ArmParam---------------")

from ArmModel import ArmParameters as ArmParam
ArmParam = ArmParam.ArmParameters()

print("--------------Arm---------------")
from ArmModel import Arm as Arm
arm1 = Arm.Arm()
```

---

My problem is the following one :
If I run :

```
python runTest.py
```

I get an error message:

```
--------------Muscles---------------
init MusclesParameters
--------------ArmParam---------------
init ArmParameters
--------------Arm---------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ArmModel import Arm as Arm
  File "MotorControlModel/ArmModel/MusclesParameters.pxd", line 4, in init MotorControlModel.ArmModel.Arm (Arm.c:8082)
ImportError: No module named MotorControlModel.ArmModel.MusclesParameters
```

As I see in the error log, Arm.pxd is not able to link to MusclesParameters & ArmParameters. I think the path to those module is not the right one.
I tried with *cimport* and searched on the web but I didn't found how to fix this.

Could you help me with this stuff :-D

Many thanks ^-^

Thanks

---Edit 7/1/12 -------------

I figured out that all the files are well compiled, exept that they are compiled in the right folder :-S.

If I grab those *.so files and add them inside my package folder everything is running (including the intra-package dependency).

Next step is to understand why the compiler is not putting the files where I want :-D

Answer (score 0):

You must carefully read the [Python docs for package imports](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Cython follows the same rules. It *seems like*:

- You need a new `ArmModel/__init__.py`.  It can be empty, but it needs to be there.
- Your imports inside your `.pxd` files need to be either absolute or relative imports *to the package*. Here is a demonstration with both methods:

#### Arm.pxd (relative imports)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from . import MusclesParameters 
from .MusclesParameters cimport MusclesParameters

from . import ArmParameters
from .ArmParameters cimport ArmParameters

cdef class Arm:
...
```

#### Arm.pxd (absolute imports)

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from ArmModel import MusclesParameters 
from ArmModel.MusclesParameters cimport MusclesParameters

from ArmModel import ArmParameters
from ArmModel.ArmParameters cimport ArmParameters

cdef class Arm:
...
```

- It's not clear how you're compiling the Cython modules, but in my experiments, if you're using `cythonize -b <module.pyx>`, you will have to run this from outside the package, else compilation fails with a *missing cimport in module '.'* error.
- If you're using a `setup.py` to do the compiling, it should all just work if you follow the tutorial guidelines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer..
Sorry for the late reply, I was overbooked with school projects.

I figured out that all the files are well compiled, exept that they are compiled in the right folder :-S.

If I grab those *.so files and add them inside my package folder everything is running (including the intra-package dependency).

Comment: Sorry to up the thread, but it seem it wasn't only a pbm of compilation :S.
I tried your solution and read a lot of documentation on [Sharing Extension Types](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html).
But when I run *runTest.py*, I still get the old error. This problem is driving me mad (as I don't think is very complicated to solve).
Could youhelp me on this before It mate me blow a fuse ^^.
My code is on on [github](https://github.com/kosenhitatchi/ArmModelPython-cython/tree/cythonise_armModel) if you want to have a overall look.

Comment: My compilation script is here [Cythonize_ArmModel.py](https://github.com/kosenhitatchi/ArmModelPython-cython/tree/cythonise_armModel/method_compilation_cython) and the code I'm cythonising is here [/ArmModel](https://github.com/kosenhitatchi/ArmModelPython-cython/tree/cythonise_armModel/MotorControlModel/ArmModel).

Many Thanks